# How to use PyQGIS ( Python QGIS API ) to open/close Update Drawing Order checkbox in QGIS2's Layers (Legend Interface)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-2, legend, rendering

Thanks qgis 2, the Legend Interface (layers dockwidget) now has **Update Drawing Order** check box on right-click mouse context menu. I think this feature can let user temporally closes rendering, then changes order of layers without no-used rendering.
And how to use PyQGIS control this feature??

Btw, the PyQGIS API **iface.legendInterface().moveLayer( layer, group_index )**
in qgis, group_index include any layer and group (on top level?), but
in qgis2, group_index just include group

e.g. If the layer/group structure:

```
--layer1  
--group1  
  --layer2  
  --layer3
```

To move layer1 to group 1
in qgis, use qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().moveLayer( layer1, 1 )
in qgis2, use iface.legendInterface().moveLayer( layer1, 0 )

Edit:
I use moveLayer, but mapCanvas doesn't refresh, even I use mapCanvas.refresh()

```
iface.legendInterface().moveLayer( iface.activeLayer(), 0) # activeLayer move to top of gruop in layer legend, but mapCanvas doesn't refresh
iface.mapCanvas().refresh() #nothing happened
```

But I uncheck and then check Update Drawing Order, it works.
How could I refresh mapCanvas after layer moved??
If I can use PyQGIS to uncheck and check Update Drawing Order, it will work.

Comment: Update Drawing Order is used to tell QGIS if it should let the legend or the Layer Order dialog control the rendering order of layers.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me :). When Update Drawing Order is unchecked, I still can use PyQGIS API to do rendering.

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I think when I use moveLayer(), QGIS will rendering for me, but now I tested, It's not.
I want to save rendering time, e.g. I want to 
1. add new layer  
2. move some layers to group  
3. rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop rendering you need to call:

```
canvas.freeze(True)
```

then to undo:

```
canvas.freeze(False)
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use this concept when add some layers without rendering each steps.